# Kusto UDF on dynamic array (map string values)

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to apply a simple transformation on an array of strings (dynamic type).

For the sake of the example, I want to map an array of strings. Each string to wrap in dashes - `["a", "b", "c"] => ["---a---", "---b---", "---c---"]`

I tried:

```
let foof = (fooTable: dynamic) {
fooTable | mv-apply fooTable on ( project abc=strcat("---", fooTable, "---") | summarize make_list(abc))
};
let fooTable = datatable(str: string, record: dynamic) [
    "name1", dynamic(["a", "b", "c"]),
    "name2", dynamic(["a", "b", "c"]),
    "name3", dynamic(["a", "b", "c"]),
];
fooTable | project abc=foof(record)
```

I'm expecting to get the mapped three rows (the UDF applied on each row).

Seems like I got it right without the UDF:

```
fooTable | mv-apply record on (
    project abc=strcat("--", record, "---") | summarize make_list(abc)
)
```

but I'm doing something wrong with the UDF.

But I get:

```
Operator source expression should be table or column
```

I'm trying to change only the UDF, so in the KQL I'll only call the UDF on the given column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your UDF should have a tabular argument instead of a scalar one, and you can use the `invoke` operator:

```
let foof = (fooTable: (record: dynamic)) {
fooTable | mv-apply record on ( project abc=strcat("---", record, "---") | summarize abc = make_list(abc))
};
let fooTable = datatable(str: string, record: dynamic) [
    "name1", dynamic(["a", "b", "c"]),
    "name2", dynamic(["a", "b", "c"]),
    "name3", dynamic(["a", "b", "c"]),
];
fooTable | invoke foof() // you can also replace this line with "foof(fooTable)"
```

| str | abc |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | [ "---a---", "---b---", "---c---" ] |
| name2 | [ "---a---", "---b---", "---c---" ] |
| name3 | [ "---a---", "---b---", "---c---" ] |

Regarding your comments -

- assuming I understood your verbal description correctly - you could try this:
- otherwise, please clarify/provide an example as requested.

```
let some_variable = dynamic(['a','b','c']);
let foof = (some_variable: dynamic) {
    toscalar(
        print some_variable
        | mv-apply v = some_variable on ( project v = strcat("---", v, "---"))
        | summarize make_set(v)
    );
};
let T = datatable(str: string) [
    "---abc---",
    "---a---",
    "---b---d---c",
];
T
| where str has_any (foof(some_variable))
```

| str |
| --- |
| ---a--- |
| ---b---d---c |

Comment: thanks. How I can make this work when the `record` isn't from the table, but from a variable? What I'm trying to do is `... | where <some column> has_any foof(<some variable>)`. basically checking is some column in my table `has_any` a variable list I want to transform.

Comment: you may want to try and clarify what you're trying to do using an example, that include a sample input, and the expected output. without that, it's not clear enough (to me, at least)

Comment: Sure. basically running this UDF on a variable. I have this variable `let data = dynamic(["a", "b", "c"]);` already given, and I want to apply the UDF on this variable `data`.